# Rails: ORA-00911 error while executing query, doesn't appear when copy and pasted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

We had some queries saved in a secondary database which are used to query an Oracle Database.

It kept showing us the ORA-00911 Invalid Character error, but we couldn't find it.

We searched for extra colons, semi-colons or comma as other suggested but we couldn't find it.

We then printed the query to the HTML output, copied it and pasted it on the console and it worked.

Are there any other possible characters that could fail?

Answer (score 0):

What we finally did was to paste the query from the console to Visual Studio Code, and then we installed the extension [Highlight Bad Chars](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wengerk.highlight-bad-chars). That showed us that some invalid characters (** **) were placed in the text.

We took the queries right from our Confluence site, maybe it got confused with some markup element that brought the error.